# triggered jenkins job does not spawn a job in queue

Tags: jenkins, triggers

We have a CI wherein a job (JOB A) will trigger multiple jobs (JOB B, JOB C, JOB D) downstream. These jobs will then trigger a build from another job (JOB E).

So it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBw1d.jpg). However, in the job queue, only two builds of JOB E (the ones triggered by JOB B and JOB C) are running. JOB D is waiting for JOB E to complete even though there is no corresponding running build. These jobs are spawned by the [Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger). This does not happen all the time.

So here are my questions:

1. What seems to be the problem?
2. Should there be logs for this, where can I find it?

Comment: How many executors do you have available? If you have all the executors filled with Job B, C, E, and maybe some other jobs, then no more can run until another one completes.

Comment: But shouldn't we see it in the Build Queue? In my scenario, the triggered job is simply missing. We can't even see an error which is the reason I'm asking if there are logs present for this.